# what contact, if any, did Owen and Beru Lars have with Obi-Wan?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars, Episode 4, Owen Lars appears to be mistrustful of Obi-Wan.  I presume he knows who Luke's father is, and obviously Obi-Wan is the one who drops off Luke with Owen and Beru.  Is there any information on the relationship between the Lars' and Obi-Wan on Tatooine?  I suppose the real subtext of this question is:

What is it that caused Owen to be mistrustful?  Was it just out of fear for Luke, knowing what Obi-Wan planned for him as part of the rebellion, or was there anything in their history, post Episode 3, that explains it?